# How to make one class react to a button pressed in another?

Tags: java, swing, button

Hi I am new to programming and trying to figure things out as I go. Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to make a button in one class that when pressed, the other class knows.

Here is the first class that contains the testWindow method that I want to call in my other class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;    
public class TestWindow {
    public static void testWindow() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JLabel text = new JLabel("this is a test!",SwingConstants.CENTER);
      text.setBounds(0,30,300,50);

      JButton button = new JButton("Start");
      button.setBounds(100,100,100,40);

      frame.add(text);
      frame.add(button);
      frame.setSize(300,200);
      frame.setLayout(null);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //I don't know what to put here
         }
      }); 
   }
}
```

And here is the second class where I want to use my testWindow method.

```
public class MainTest extends TestWindow {
   public static void main(String[] arg){
      testWindow();
      //other stuff that happens when "start" is pressed
   } 
}
```

When I run the MainTest class, the testWindow appears as it should. But when the "start" button is pressed, I want to close that frame then do other actions in the main method. How would I go about that?

Comment: `frame.dispose()` should work.

Comment: @inavda: nope. It won't prevent the main method code from running while the window is displayed.

Comment: right - good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run the MainTest class, the testWindow appears as it should. But when the "start" button is pressed, I want to close that frame then do other actions in the main method. How would I go about that?

You're desiring the functionality of a *modal* dialog, a window that halts program flow until it has been dealt with. And in this situation you shouldn't be using a JFrame which does not allow for this type of modality, but rather a Swing modal dialog such as a JOptionPane or a JDialog that you create, make modal, and display. Then the GUI program flow halt until the dialog window is no longer visible.

If you do this, all the button's action listener has to do is to close the dialog window that holds it, that's it.

---

Side note: You're misusing inheritance here, as your MainTest class should most definitely **not** extend from the TestWindow class. While it may not matter in this simple code, it can and will cause problems in future code.

---

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestWindow {
    public static void testWindow() {
        // JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        final JDialog frame = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Test", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel text = new JLabel("this is a test!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        // text.setBounds(0, 30, 300, 50);

        JButton button = new JButton("Start");
        // button.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 40);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        int eb = 15;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(eb, eb));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(eb, eb, eb, eb));
        panel.add(text, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        // frame.setSize(300, 200);
        // frame.setLayout(null);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTestWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TestWindow.testWindow();
            System.out.println("Called after test window no longer visible");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nicole: by calling the static method explicitly off the class, as per my example above: `TestWindow.testWindow();`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I am a bit confused by the purpose of the panel created after initializing eb. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Nicole: you've got "bad code"™ in  your posted code where you're setting bounds and using null layouts, things that you should avoid like the plague. The JPanel was created to simplify the adding of components to your GUI without resorting to null layout kludges. Learn the layout managers and use them.